# PHP in _POST data

Tags: php, html

Recently I've come across a situation to where using a dynamic variable in a _POST setting is valuable, but it doesn't seem to work.  For example:

```
for($i = 0; $i<$limit; $i++){
    if (isset($_POST['value_{$i}'])){
    // do something
    }
}
```

The values from _POST work fine; if I hard code a '1' or a '2' in there, I get my data.  It just doesn't seem to agree with the {$i} inside the _POST.  Does anybody know why?

Comment: pls provide a sample index.. is it like value_1 or value_{1}?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use double quotes to parse variables in strings, eg

```
for($i = 0; $i<$limit; $i++){
    if (isset($_POST["value_{$i}"])){
    // do something
    }
}
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

Answer (score 2):

You can use it with single quote but concatenate it

```
for($i = 0; $i<$limit; $i++){
        if (isset($_POST['value_'.$i])){
        }
    }
```